# System.config() call on <head> or <body>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I usually like to add my  tags to the bottom of my page. But on a lot of the examples that I see online, the call to Systemjs's config is on the  tag. I've moved the System.config() script to the bottom of the page, and everything still works as expected.

So my question is... Will I encounter any issues by putting the System.config() call at the bottom of the page, or is it safe to do so?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: It doesn't matter, Systemjs loads after document ready, kind of like jQuery.

Comment: @Baruch could you make an answer from that comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's recommended to have JavaScript code at the bottom of the HTML page is so it only runs after the document has been loaded.

SystemJS, like many JS libraries, have a fallback for this already in their framework so it doesn't matter much where you add the `<script>` tag.

Example of this would be jQuery's `$(document).ready( ... );` wrapper.

Comment: @Brauch, that makes total sense!... Thanks a lot concise answer! :D